# Howling sound when accelerating

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, noise

I have a 2007 Ford Ranger that makes a faint howling sound when I'm accelerating, usually after being idle at a stoplight. I've tried slowly revving in neutral and I didn't hear the same noise. Definitely is something out of the ordinary, I know what my truck **should** sound like. Started today. What could it be?

94k miles

5 speed Auto-tranny

2.3 liter 4 cylinder

UPDATE: Ok, weird. I had to take my truck to the shop anyways for an oil change, and I asked them to take a look at the problem that I'm having and explain how to reproduce it and everything. Turns out they couldn't find the problem or reproduce it and now, neither can I. Could an oil change really be the difference in that noise or not?

Comment: Can you determine the side of the noise by chance? Passenger/Drivers side? Also, does it go away if you were to switch to neutral while it was happening or take your foot off the gas pedal?

Comment: I think its only when driving, so that's hard to tell. But I'll make an update later. If I take my foot off the gas, yes it stops.

Comment: Before checking if it's side dependent, see if you can put it in neutral and rev it and reproduce the noise. If it doesn't come up in neutral try to _break torque_ the truck (e-brake on 100%, left foot firmly on the brake, and with your other foot give it a little gas, don't floor it for obvious reasons =) )

Comment: Mike, Also, is let me know if noise favors the front or rear of the vehicle?

Comment: Front, I want to say drivers side...it usually happens around 2500 RPMs, but that's not to say it isn't noticeable, it just gets louder after 2500 RPMs.

Comment: Is the truck a 4x4?

Comment: i want to say it has the option to, but I'm leaning on no.

Comment: If possible, could you supply the 5th, 6th, and, 7th Positions in the vehicles VIN number. (R10?)

Comment: I gave an update...

Comment: Not likely. Keep an eye on it and post if it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, it was the alternator that was getting weak or eventually dying. I took my car to the shop because my battery light came on whenever I started one morning and eventually had to tow it to the shop because my car died. The alternator broke and the bearings in the water pump were shot and needed replacing, according to the shop. Now with a new alternator and a new water pump, there is no rattle.